# Detect rows which have only one number in a column

Tags: r

I face a problem where my dataframe

```
data.frame(mytest = c(0.43,0,0), additional = c(0,323,41.2), col = c(0,23.1,0.324))
```

Is it possible to detect which rows have only one number and remove them totally from the data.frame?
results after removal:

```
data.frame(mytest = c(0,0), additional = c(323,41.2), col = c(23.1,0.324))
```

Comment: Maybe this could help: `df1[rowSums(df1>0)>1,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `rowSums` answer from @Duck would work the best but here is an alternative with row-wise `apply` :

```
df[apply(df != 0, 1, sum) > 1, ]

#  mytest additional    col
#2      0      323.0 23.100
#3      0       41.2  0.324
```

We select rows where number of non-zero values in a row is greater than 1.